# TypeScript class which is generic of concrete of generic

Tags: typescript

My http response for a login operation:

```
interface ILoginResponse {   // ok
  message: string
  token: string;
}
```

And that plugs into a generic response, that I want to use for all sorts of http responses:

```
interface IResponse<TResponseData> {    // ok
  Data: TResponseData;
  Errors: string[];
  Status: number;
}
```

Which I wanted to use in a generic abstract service like this:

```
abstract class HttpService<TRequest, IResponse<TResponseData>> {   // ERROR
  protected onSuccess(responseData: TResponseData);  // I want to do this (hide the wrapper from the subclass)
}
```

Which I wanted to extend for various http operations like this:

```
class LoginService extends HttpService<ILoginRequest, ILoginResponse> { }  // ok
```

The problem is in the `HttpService` class: `"Cannot find name 'TResponseData'"`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can constrain the second parameter to extends `IResponse`:

```
abstract class HttpService<TRequest, TResponse extends IResponse<any>> { }
```

Or you can use `TResponseData` and use `IResponse<TResponseData>` anywhere you need the response:

```
abstract class HttpService<TRequest, TResponseData> { 
    doRequest(request: TRequest) : IResponse<TResponseData>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but doesn't give me what I was hoping for - you see, this means in the subclass I must use `IResponse<ILoginResponse>` which is ok, but I wanted to be able to use the inner type by itself `ILoginResponse`. I wanted to hide the wrapper from the subclass. I assume that isn't possible?

Comment: For example, I edited the question, I added `protected onSuccess(responseData: TResponseData);` to the baseclass so you see what I mean.